# Exercise 2.2 in Atiyah and Macdonald's Introduction to Commutative Algebra.

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra

I am asked to prove that $(N:P) = Ann((N+P)/N)$, where $N,P$ are submodules of a module $M$, and $x\in (N:P) \Leftrightarrow xP \subset N$.

I was thinking along the following lines:
$$ x\in Ann((N+P)/N) \Leftrightarrow x((N+P)/N) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x(N+P) \subset N \Leftrightarrow xP\subset N$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: @user26857 yes, it's on page 20, the chapter on modules.

Comment: Sorry, thank you both @user26857 and Thomas.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, would the proof be the same if instead of $P$ we had $M$? My guess is yes, since $M$ is a submodule of itself. Is that true?